# How to store a collection of classes of the type 'Class<T>' without a defining T type

Tags: c#

I've run into a little difficulty and I'm not sure how best to solve this issue.

I wrote a class that expects data type to be specified upon the creation of a new instance. Much like in the same way as the `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>` class that stores a number of items of a specified type. However my class doesn't has the same or similar function as the `List<T>` class does.

Upon creation of a new instance of my class, for example:

```
string phrase = "Some string type data.";
MyClass<string> data = new MyClass<string>( () => phrase );
```

Afterwards my class would provide a number of methods that would give a result regardless of the type of data being imparted into `MyClass<T>` (where `T` is the data type). Doesn't matter if it is string, bool, int, or any kind.

I've tested my class and it works as expected, now how can I store a number of elements of `MyClass` but each element with different imparted data type, inside a collection class such as `List<>`.

Let me exemplify (code will contain syntax errors since I'm not sure how to write correctly):

```
// My intent... Not sure how to do it.
string phrase = "Some string data type.";
int number = 23;
bool boolData = false;

List<MyClass<T>> list = new List<MyClass<T>>();

list.Add( new MyClass<string>( () => phrase ) );
list.Add( new MyClass<int>( () => number ) );
list.add( new MyClass<bool>( () => boolData ) );
```

As you see I don't know how to store a number of element of MyClass with different imparted data types, if they were all the same imparted data type, I wouldn't be having this issue.

For example:

```
// How it should be done. But not what I need.
string phrase1 = "Hello Phrase 1.";
string phrase2 = "Hello Phrase 2.";

List<MyClass<string>> list = new List<MyClass<string>>();

list.Add(new MyClass<string>( () => phrase1) );
list.Add(new MyClass<string>( () => phrase2) );
```

If this was what I wanted to accomplish, I wouldn't have a problem, but since I want to accomplish what I exemplified before this last example, I'm just not sure how to best do it.

Basically thats my issue, I've provided a few basic examples because I believe my question might be a bit odd, and to be honest my terminology wouldn't not be adequate I think.

This is probably quite simple for some of you. My thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Typically you'd create a non-generic base class (or interface) for the generic type:

```
abstract class MyClass // Or interface
{
    // Anything useful but non-generic here
}

class MyClass<T> : MyClass
{
    // Anything using T
}
```

Then you can just create a `List<MyClass>`. Of course to get at any of the members within `MyClass<T>` you'll need to know the right `T` to cast to, but I think that's unavoidable.

Of course this doesn't help much if you don't control `MyClass<T>` and it doesn't provide a useful base class - but there's nothing in C# to help you with this situation.

Comment: Can `is` be used to determine the object's actual type later, or will it always "evaluate" to only the base type (or interface)?

Comment: @TiesonT.: "is" would work fine later on, yes. There's no type erasure going on here :)

Comment: @JonSkeet: I've thought about creating a `List<object>` that way I could impart anything inside it, and sort it out later when going through the list, but I was hoping someone here would have a better idea. Yours seems to be the one, and if I remember right, `List<T>` itself originally uses your logical process.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Just came to thank you and say that your approach worked very well and is working as expected. No need for `List<object>`after all. Thanks.